libxcb-xinerama0 Library required by bitcoin-qt
I installed bitcoin core 26.1 on a Raspberry 5 (ARM Architecture) running Ubuntu 23.1. Upon running bitcoin-qt, I got the error that the library libxcb-xinerama0 is required but not installed.
It's easily fixed by installing it from the repositories (apt install libxcb-xinerama0), however, for a security conscious person this is a bit unsatisfying. Is there a reason this library is not packaged with the bitcoin core binaries?
After all you go through the hassle of verifying and cross checking all signatures of the binaries and then you have to install a third party untrusted library to run everything.
Many thanks for your answer regarding this design choice and about the safety of libxcb-xinerama0.

This might be better filed as a bug report on the Bitcoin Core repository.

Makes sense, will do that!

It is maintained by the Ubuntu Core Developers.
My suspicion is that it could depend on your X install. It looks like other libxcb packages are installed on my system; I'm wondering if this was assumed to be installed on many folks' distro's. Or, the library build might be heavily dependent on your environment.
